# Wordpress Login Page redirecting after failed login

Tags: redirect, login

Recently I changed my domain and my host. Initially the domain name was example.com on bluehost. Since last night I changed my Domain to example12.com and moved to other host Godaddy.com.

I successfully transferred the site along with the database. But the problem arises when I try to login into admin area.

I tried to setup the new admin user using this [Tutorial](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-the-wordpress-database-via-mysql/). When ever there is a failed login the wordpress redirect itself to the example.com instead of example12.com

Can you please tell me where the problem could be ?

Thank you

Comment: Please check your wp-config as well as your blog domain inside the wp_options table to see what domains are listed. You may also have to resave your permalinks depending on the changes you made.

Comment: Worked fine.! :)

Comment: So what was it that worked so I can put it as an answer? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check your wp-config as well as your blog domain inside the wp_options table to see what domains are listed. The domains may be referencing the original domains. You may also have to resave your permalinks depending on the changes you made.

There is some additional materials in the codex to help you narrow it down:

[Moving Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)